# Package.json for server and client

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install, node-modules

I want to install **package.json** for client side from my server side **package.json** as the server side is using node and client side is using angular 2 
directory structure

```
server-app

--bin

--node_modules

--package.json

--client-app

     --app

     --node_modules

     --package.json
```

now the problem is:

I have to run this command **npm install** from **server app folder** and also from **server-app/client-app** folder separately this will create deployment issues

what I want is to run only one time **npm install** from i.e **server-app** and it will automatically install the server-app package.json and client-side-app 
package.json too.
Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Did you read this? https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths

Answer (score 7):

I think what you need is a npm module called **concurrently**.

With **concurrently** installed in your root folder you can run multiple custom npm scripts.
For example: you can create 2 separate scripts that are installing the dependencies (client-install and server-install) and then create install-all-deps script that will run both scripts one after another and install all deps in both directories.

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "client-install"  : "cd client && npm install",
        "server-install"  : "cd server && npm install",
        "install-all-deps": "concurrently \"npm run server-install\" \"npm run client-install\""
    }
}
```

Here is the npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently. Quoting doc:

> Run multiple commands concurrently. Like npm run watch-js & npm run
>   watch-less but better.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The above scripts need to be included in server's or client's package.json ?

Comment: It doesn't matter as long as it is in the root directory.

Answer (score 6):

Structure your application in the following way,

```
app
   --server-app        
   --client-app       
   --node_modules
   --package.json
```

This way you can have single **package.json** file

Comment: I know it but angular2 create problems while doing this it couldn't route back

Comment: Did u tried the structure using any generators like [MEAN Generator](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack)

Comment: yeah its for angular 1

Comment: can u post the github link of that generator

Comment: Ckeckout this [App structure](https://angular-fullstack.github.io/get-started/overview/#project-root) of the generator which i mentioned before. You can see it has a single package.json file in its root. This is a recommended structure for a MEAN Stack. Try to use this generator. By the way verify the answer so it will helpful for others with this kind of issue. cheers!!